# Why does std::sort work when the comparison function uses greater-than (>), but not greater-than-or-equal (>=)?

Tags: c++, c++11

On WIN32, Visual Studio 2022.  When I define a `vector<int>` containing one hundred 0s and sort it with the code below, an exception "invalid comparator" throws.

```
vector<int> v(100, 0);
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const int& a, const int& b)
    {
        return a >= b;
    });
```

However, if I use `return a > b`, it will execute well.  Why is that?

Comment: The standard requires a "strict weak ordering", in particular `comp(a,a)` must be false. (start from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort , click on `Compare`, etc)

Comment: Note that VC's C++ standard library has extra debug code to help catch comparisons that don't implement strict weak ordering.  If the same sort works (or appears to work) on another platform or in a "Release" build, it's almost always because the comparison isn't quite right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This is just how it is required to work](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). You need [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings).

For the rationale, I believe that the sufficient explanation is that this enables you to determine whether those elements are equal (useful for e.g. `std::set`s). <s>`<=` or `>=` can't do that</s>.

`<=` or `>=` can also do that, but it seems like it was just decided to use `<` instead of any other relation. With this decision in mind, standard library facilities are implemented and they [heavily rely on it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71979257/7151494).

Comment: Thanks very much. Your answer benefits me a lot.

Comment: @unknown my pleasure. Consider accepting it by clicking the tick just below the score to indicate that it solved your problem / answered your question, so future visitors will be able to quickly identify the solution / relevant information.

Comment: @unknown Looks like the accepting didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The **problem** is that the *comparator*(aka comparing function) that you've provided does not implement a *strict-weak-ordering* and thus it **violates** a precondition of `std::sort` leading to **undefined behavior**.

From [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):

> **comp**  -   comparison function object (i.e. **an object that satisfies the requirements of Compare**) which returns ​true if the first argument is less than (i.e. is ordered before) the second.

And from [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare):

> The return value of the function call operation applied to an object of a type satisfying Compare, when contextually converted to bool, yields true if the first argument of the call appears before the second in the ***strict weak ordering relation*** induced by this type, and false otherwise.

This basically means that the comparator function `Compare` that we provide should not evaluate to `true` for both of the expressions: `Compare(x, y)` and `Compare(y, x)` where `x` and `y` are some arguments. Otherwise, the comparator does not obey the strict-weak-ordering.

To solve this you should replace the `>=` with `>`.